How to get taller
I am 14 years old and only 155 cm my mother is 150 cm and my father is 170 how can I get taller I am going to the gym and I am afraid of stopping to get taller because of weight lifting and If it really affects my growth can I do anything to keep getting taller

Your parents being shorter are not necessary a good indicator of your final height; my parents (and aunts and uncles) are all shorter than me and most of my cousins. At 14 you still have a good few years of growth to go.

The only way to know if you have stopped growing is to have xrays done on the epiphyseal plates in your long bones. If you are fully grown (Which I doubt at 14), the only way to get taller is very expensive, very painful surgery.

Your height is almost exclusively determined by the amount of somatotropin (growth hormone or GH for short) produced in your pituitary gland (given you do not suffer any kind of severe injury or malnutrition). This is predominantly determined by your genes but, to some amount, positively influenced by (among others):

sport
testosterone (for males; for biologically female persons it is estrogen!)
protein-rich nutrition (within reasonable bounds!, moderated over ghrelin)

Thus, weightlifting (which also raises testosterone levels, which in turn raise GH levels) and protein-rich nutrition can "help" to increase your GH burst levels but whether this will even make a significant difference as of your final body height is questionable.
That said, keep cool and continue to work hard if that's what you enjoy. Some people have their growth later or more stable. You can grow well into your twenties if that is how your genetics work.

Can you cite studies showing that sport has increased people's heights?  Or that adding protein to diet did so?  Or that (gasp) supplementing with testosterone/estrogen did so?  Of course, the latter two can have significant dangers.  (Well, sport does too, but those dangers are typically more obvious.)

Unfortunately, although well-intentioned, I could see this answer leading people down a self-harming path.  Keep in mind the OP is only 14.  When you tell a 14 year old, who is so concerned about their height that they are posting online about it, that testosterone/estrogen may lead to them being taller, what do you think may happen?

@EndAnti-SemiticHate No matter the age of the poster, I mentioned testosterone primarily because its levels are closely correlated to variations in somatotropin levels. Also, exercise is one of the most potent stimulants for somatotropin/growth hormone. Last but not least, I explicitly wrote that a significant effect of sports over genetics will probably not happen in terms of final body height.

It's worth stating, about 40-50% of the variance in height can be attributed to genetics using large GWAS studies. Since height is a polygenic trait, a child may inherit SNPs which cause them to be significantly shorter or taller than their parent. Assuming these SNPs are inherited independently (which is not really the case because of hotspot/haplotype recombination / non-autosomal inheritance), the height of children would be a roughly normally distributed around a distribution parameterized by the parent's genetics.

As that implies, a certain amount of height is just luck. The OP's trajectory might be completely normal given his/her/their age group and genetic profile. Source for the GWAS.

One more thing, please consult a physician if you're seriously concerned about these things. They have the necessary tools (e.g. growth charts and such) to determine if there is a problem or can offer reassurance if you're on a normal trajectory.

So long as you don’t injure growth plates from bad form lifting will not affect height negatively. If anything it may increase it but not significantly in any way.
The biggest factor for height is nutrition and genetics. No gym protocol, no one on the internet that has a growing technique, just your genetics. You may be shorter like your mom, taller like your dad, or maybe really tall like a great great grandfather you don’t know about.

“as you don’t injure growth plates from bad form lifting” There is exactly zero evidence that this is even possible.
